# I am using masonry, its not giving proper height to the container, that why tiles inside misplacing

Tags: html, css, jquery-masonry

I am using masonry for showing the contents, masonry.desandro.com, problem is its not giving proper height to the container, as if you know that, masonry dynamically gives height to container and margin style to inside items, but its not working as it should. here is the masonry js.

```
$(function(){
      $('#ItemContainer').masonry({
        // options
        itemSelector : '.item'
      });
    });
```

and this is my html skeleton

```
<html><body>
<div id="content">
  <ul id="ItemContainer">
    <li class="item">here li content with block style</li>
    ....more li's
  </ul>
</div>
</body></html>
```

but when I set the height for each li then it works fine, but an image in it can have any height, so i have to keep its height on auto. second row of items are overlapping on first upto half of first, and third on second and so on...everytime its giving 426px of height to the ItemContainer.

here i have uploaded my code... www.testingmycode.comuv.com/rough2.html ...please do checkout. its showing unwanted behavior, press reload, the tiles are arranged like that of card game in MS windows, and when you resize the window, they are arranged properly...press reload button of browser 2-3 times, resize window to see them. please do checkout.

Comment: Have a read of the introduction page and make sure your set-up is using their recommended practices of column width etc: http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/intro.html

Comment: @BillyMoat here i have uploaded my code...<http://testingmycode.comuv.com/rough2.html> please do checkout. its showing unwanted behavior, press reload, the tiles are arranged like that of card game in MS windows, and when you resize the window, they are arranged properly...press reload, resize window to see them. please do checkout.

Answer (score 6):

I can't see your code, but you have to use the `imagesLoaded()` method.

```
var $container = $('#container');
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $container.masonry({
    itemSelector : '.item',
    columnWidth : 240
  });
});
```

Comment: I had a similar issue.  This seemed to work well for me.  Thanks!

Comment: Yep, worked for me. You might need to use the imagesLoaded twice. E.g. if you load images via ajax, you also need to wait for those images to be fully loaded.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem.  We have all the required elements and the images are loaded.  The problem is that all the elements within the LI element, including the LI element itself, have "auto" as their height property.  That makes the height inaccessible to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think its the problem with clearing the divs..

Put this code in some places in yer code and check..

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

This usually happens if yu have used float somewhere, and it will work properly once yu put it

Comment: you sure you added that code inside your content, outside content, inside ul, at the end of ul and all that??

Comment: @klrA here i have uploaded my code...  testingmycode.comuv.com/rough2.html please do checkout. its showing unwanted behavior, press reload, the tiles are arranged like that of card game in MS windows, and when you resize the window, they are arranged properly...press reload, resize window to see them. please do checkout